# Upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10, cannot boot anymore, boot repair log attached

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, initramfs, 19.10

I updated my Ubuntu to 19.10 and now my system boots only to BusyBox/initramfs command line. I have my root and also boot partition encrypted, and I guess some entries to mount these partitions got lost during the upgrade.

I was looking for a solution, but actually don't know where to start fixing this. Please have a look at my Ubuntu boot repair log [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/89KTpZDjsb/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

19.10 comes with a new version of [Grub 2.04 that many have reported bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1848892) with.

A common solution is to turn off [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) in BIOS. However other options are detailed in the bug reports and there other things to try if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have a Windows partition along with your Ubuntu one because I can see many NTFS errors.

Basically something during installation messed up your partitions. You have to fix both, Linux and Windows booting.

For the Linux part, use an USB to live boot.

Then install boot repair if it isn't installed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

> The first line enables universe in order to install the (bit down the tree) `python` dependency

And then launch it with:

```
sudo boot-repair
```

And just follow the instructions.

I would recommend to fix Windows first. Because fixing Linux probably won't fix Windows booting. For Windows you would have to use a USB created with the Windows Media Creation Tool. Boot to USB and select repair. Repair partition/MBR and check system options.

Comment: thanks, the `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"` before the others helped me

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I did run boot-repair prior to asking my question. That's where the log came from, and it couldn't do anything to repair booting. I ended up doing fresh installs..

Answer (score 0):

I have a recent model desktop ASUS motherboard, and upgrading the BIOS helped with grub issues of 19.10

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  While this may technically answer the question, it would be far better to expand and explain *why* this will help the OP.  As it is, you say it "helped with grub issues," but grub issues are a vast category of problems.  Why do you think this will help in this particular case?  Without some good reason why this applies here, it's really more of a comment than an answer.  Please [edit] to be more precise.  Thanks!

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I'm afraid you really do need to be more specific.  If every possible direction that a person could go for resolution of their problem were posted as an answer, posts would very quickly get flooded with noise, making Ask Ubuntu very little different from a forum.  Do take the  [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and see the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, when you expand your answer, it would be great if you could include a bit more detail on your comment "lots of people have had success by upgrading their BIOS."  What is the common thread: why do you believe that the previous cases give evidence that it will help in this case?